# I am trying to create non cancellable/dismiss notification trigger with my foreground service... but is not working

Tags: android, android-14

I am trying to create non cancellable/dismiss notification trigger with my foreground service... but is not working

Here is my Service class code...

```
class MyService : Service() {

    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "MediaChannel"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    }
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    
    
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
    
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        playDefaultRingtone()
        return START_STICKY
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
        mediaPlayer?.release()
        stopForeground(true)  // Remove the notification when the service is destroyed
    }
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForegroundService()
    }
    
    private fun startForegroundService() {
    
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Media Player",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    
            // Create a notification
            val notification: Notification = Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Media Player")
                .setContentText("Playing...")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .build()
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ServiceCompat.startForeground(this, NOTIFICATION_ID ,notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)
            } else {
                startForeground(1, notification)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun playDefaultRingtone() {
        val defaultRingtoneUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
    
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, defaultRingtoneUri)
        mediaPlayer?.isLooping = true
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }
```

Here is my manifest permission...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

<service
android:name=".MyService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false"
android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback" />
```

Notification triggered with foreground service not be dismiss until service is stopped.